# USB 5V 2.1A Charger Destroys Device

Tags: charging, usb-device

I have a USB powered device with an internal Li-Ion battery that has overheated and died.  After looking for similar events online I found that charging on a 2.1A charger can damage or destroy the device.  I thought that chargers rated for 2.1A means that is maximum output.  What could cause this kind of failure?

Comment: Rubbish charging circuitry.

Comment: You're mixing up the units. You mean 2100 mA or 2.1 A (which are the same). If you really meant 2.1 mA, that would only be enough to charge a watch battery.

Comment: Seems like the charger avoid the necessary OCP , OVP , ORP or UVP protection circuit as one of the faults may have been the cause. The protections are common to better charger boards yet not that expensive.

Comment: Yes, 2.1 A, sorry

Comment: If it's USB powered then the actual charger is in the device, not the bit that plugs into the wall.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by:

1. faulty or low quality battery
2. faulty external power source (5V 2.1A) which could push more than 5V and so fry circuitry inside your device
3. faulty or low quality charging circuit inside your device which could stress the battery (it could push more than 4.2V to li-ion battery, or could push excessive current to the battery)

Answer (score 0):

A charge current of only 2.1mA is extremely low. Are you sure?
A Lithium battery can overheat and die if a charge is attempted after it has been discharged too low (less than 3V). Then the lithium ions turn into pure metallic Lithium and short the battery cell and the metallic Lithium burns like a fuel.

Comment: The internal short is caused by copper deposition, and it is the organic solvent in the electrolyte that burns.

Comment: Woops, I ment 2.1A

Comment: Then why does the title of your question still read '2.1ma' instead of 2.1 A?